Is there a phrase for someone who's really bad at cooking?
I'm looking for a phrase that describes someone who's really bad at cooking, similar to 'green fingers' for someone who's good at gardening. There doesn't seem to be any such phrase from a Google search, other than 'bad cook'.
If there is no such phrase, some kind of striking expression with the same meaning would also be OK.

Need help insulting someone? Maybe not the best site here.

Yeah, but OP does not necessarily mean to insult someone, probably just curious about new phrases here.

By the way, the U.S. version of your example idiom is "green thumb". This is the first time I've heard of "green fingers". https://english.stackexchange.com/q/32764

Sometimes the correct answer is "there isn't one."

Maybe ask on [Cooking.SE]!

I think you need a better example than "green fingers". One that is in common use and that exemplifies being bad at something!

@MartinF "green fingers" is in common use in UK.

What prevents me from coining the term brewpotter? I think that almost everyone will instantly understand what you are trying to express :-)

@YosefBaskin And yet, there is a dedicated tag for [pejorative language]

@MartinF "Brown thumb" then. I think the parallel is clear enough.

@MartinF, perhaps a good parallel would be "two left feet" for someone who cannot dance well.

I've heard "can't make toast without a recipe" but suspect that isn't a widely used phrase.

My husband's name is Travis.

Kitchen disaster is an option, drawing on this sense of the word disaster:

2 :someone or something that is very bad: such as 
a :someone or something that is extremely unsuccessful
Merriam-Webster

An example usage in the wild:

After several days of harvesting bowls full of juicy blackberries, I was ready to turn them into jam. Faithful readers (all five of you) will recall that I am a kitchen disaster and not much of a gardener either.
marbleheadweeklynews

You could also phrase like:

He is a total/complete disaster at cooking.


This feels like the most suitable option to me, considering the context

I'm accepting this answer because it works best with my use case.

In my experience (and according to Ngram) more frequently phrased as a disaster in the kitchen.

To refer to a person with no kitchen skills, you could say they couldn't boil water, indicating even the simplest tasks are beyond their ability. It might be a better fit to refer to someone who doesn't cook because they don't know how or aren't interested, rather than someone who cooks often but badly.

As mentioned, in essence, by Stuart F.

Couldn't boil an egg is another common expression, although it looks like couldn't boil water is used slightly more often. Ngram.

@PeterShor Possibly (as is often the case) a US/UK thing... in the UK I've never heard "...water" before seeing this answer, but "...an egg" is common.

I thought the common phrase was "could burn water" for being a bad cook.

@MartinF That phrase is likely derived from "Couldn't boil water", as a humorous variant.  As is, "He could boil water, but he called it soup."

The problem with the phrase "burn water" is that "burn" is ambiguous. It could mean that water catches fire as well as that it turns black and sticks to the bottom of a pot, like "to scorch". In German, the word "anbrennen" is used in this context ("Ihm brennt sogar Wasser an"), which identifies it as the second meaning in an unambiguous way. Google Ngram shows some rise in the use of "scorch water" in around 2020. Is this in some way idiomatic to native speakers, something like "He would even scorch water"?

@rexkogitans It's idiomatic, yeah. As a native US English speaker among others, I've heard the phrase "could burn water" for a bad cook more than once, including on television. Though I always took it as the first meaning of "burn" that you mention, not the second, with the ridiculousness of the concept being part of the point.

Comment rather than answer bc I don't have a reliable hard source off the top of my head, but I've heard the term "lethal chef" used to describe such a person.

@MartinF I've heard it as "could burn salad".

@rexkogitans I don’t think that’s really a problem, since water famously does neither of those two things. Whether the mental image is of a pot in flames or one with charred residue stuck to its bottom doesn’t make much difference in terms of likelihood that it’ll actually happen.

I'm sure there are many.
"Could burn water"
is my all time favourite.  I've heard it a lot colloqially - here's a gif of when Hank says it in Breaking Bad (S04E04): https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/632c1d55-acbc-4224-9309-e2de3978f3ed/gif
I find it superior to "couldn't boil water" as boiling water can actually be difficult in some circumstances (windy, poor flame, etc), whereas burning water should be impossible, fancifully highlighting just how inept the cook is.

There are a few ways to burn water, but they all involve some rather, let's say exciting, chemicals.

A friend of mine managed it, in a way. He put on a small pan of water to boil and then went away and forgot about it for three hours. He came back to a melted aluminium pan that had wrecked the ring it was on.

In kitchen slang, Shoe refers to a slacker cook/chef, someone who's a bad cook.
Example: We're all gonna get fired because that shoe doesn't know how to cook a chicken.

That sounds like industry jargon, I don't think anyone who doesn't work in a restaurant would understand it.

FYI: a "shoe" is short for "shoemaker" which is a term used to describe anyone who is doing a job they are not qualified or properly trained to do, and it applies to many professions, not just cooking.  So, if you are a plumber, electrician, etc. and find something that was not done right, you might call it shoemaker's work.  This term appears to come out of the industrialization of the shoe industry that left many shoemakers out of work all at once forcing them into other professions. It was a common term up until about the 1970s when it lost its context and fell out of use in most industries

@Nosajimiki I wonder if it's related to "ultracrepidarian"?

@user888379 Yes, I would say they are similar.  The only difference being that a ultracrepidarian speaks on knowledge that they lack and a "shoemaker" works on skills that they lack.

Ne supra crepidam was recorded nearly 2000 years ago.

@Nosajimiki So what do you call a shoemaker who’s bad at making shoes, then?

@gerrit The expression "shoemaker" used label people who work outside of their profession does not appear to predate the industrial period, but I do suspect that you and user888379 are correct that it's origins were probably influenced by this Latin expression.

I think "couldn't boil water" is going to be the most commonly recognized expression in my region, as stated by Nuclear Hoagie.  But I have also heard,
"They were a chef to rival Boyardee."
The irony comes from a seemingly favorable comparison to a famous chef that actually is comparing someone to low-brow, mass-produced food.

Some readers (like me) may need some more context: Chef Boyardee is "an American brand of canned pasta products".

The funny thing is that as far as I can tell, Boiardi himself (the creator of the Boyardee brand) was a very good chef; it's just that putting almost anything in a can will make it less appetizing.

After doing a little digging I found that "meshimazu" might technically be an answer, although it might only refer to females, as it comes from the name of a female character in a manga. And it is safe to say that VERY few people would be able to understand what you mean.
Now I'd never normally use tvtropes as a source, but since you were looking for a witty insult, and comedically-impossibly bad cooks are so prevalent in children's media (for some reason), you basically designed the perfect question for it to be a source for.

I doubt that this qualifies as an English word.

Well, the question didn't specify English, but I suppose there is an argument to be made that it was implied because it was on the English Stack Exchange.  Still, I think the OP just put the question on here because it made the most sense out of the bunch of sites.  Of course, given that so few people will understand what a meshimazu is, it probably nullifies the point.  Still, I figured I may as well point it out just in case he/she was looking for something obscure.

It's not just implied in the question; this StackExchange is specifically for questions regarding the English language and its usage. A question asking for words in any language would be offtopic here.

A word that has already been borrowed into English is very different from recommending a word that could be borrowed into English.
